# Should anti seize lubricant be used on the wheel lug studs when rotating tires?

Tags: wheels, lug-nut

This my question:
Should anti seize lubricant be used on the wheel lug studs when rotating tires?
There is nothing else to add here.

Answer (score 2):

In a word: no.

Tires are rotated frequently enough (in typical cases) to not have the lugnuts seize. Moreover, lugnuts give good grip to your tire iron (or socket), meaning you can always apply sufficient torque to them to loosen them off.

Anti-seize compound is meant to be used on parts that:

- will be on for several years
- do not provide good grip to tools for removal or loosening

Comment: .. or parts that are subject to a lot of heat, like spark plugs.

Answer (score 2):

Usually there isn't a need to Anti-seize the wheel bolts/nuts.

Although sometimes it may be helpful because its a good idea to turn the bolts/nuts a good few times by hand to make sure they are not cross threaded before tightening them with a bar or gun and without lube they can be too tight to turn by hand.

It is recommend though to apply a small amount of copper grease to the face of the hub if you have Alloy wheels as aluminium corrodes quicker when touching steel and the wheels can 'stick' to the hub. Although this only usually requires hitting the tyre with a hammer this isn't an option on the side of the road with limited tools.